# Kotlin Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, kotlin

I have a simply Activity. In this activity I want start a fragment. But the Fragment doesn't start.

This is my Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    //start Homefragment
    startHomeFragment()
}

/**
 * Create Homefragment
 */
private fun  startHomeFragment() {
    val homeFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(statics.TAG) ?: HomeFragment()
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, homeFragment, statics.TAG)
            .commit()
}
```

And this is my Fragment

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

object statics {
    @JvmField val TAG = "Homefragment"
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container)

    background_home.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gc_bg_home)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the code after

```
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
```

is unreachable. Just read IDE warnings.

Also, layout becomes attached only if you returned it from `onCreateView`, i. e. `return inflater.inflate(...)`.

Comment: Thanks, you totally right! But if I put the code above the  ´return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)` I got only the toast. The layout isn't set

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin the **onCreateView** should be on this way

```
 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
       return   inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.input_field_frag, container, false)
    }
```

If you want to add somthing inside you fragment you can use **onViewCreated** method and do whatever you want here

```
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

          //Here u can call function of add listners to button...

        })
    }
```

Like this you gonna create a safe propriate code

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

```
object statics {
    @JvmField val TAG = "Homefragment"
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    Toast.makeText(activity, "HomeFragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    return inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

}
```

}

Comment: `@JvmField val TAG` may be `const val TAG`.